# Changing a Value on Key Up

Tags: javascript

This may be a simple JavaScript problem, but I really don't know what's wrong with my code.

What I would want to do is very simple, there is an input element in my template, and I would like to change the value of it whenever there is a key up.

The following is the relevant part of my code.

```js
var track = document.getElementById("id_tracking");
track.value = "a";

function track_record() {
  track.value = "b";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id_urnA_red").keyup(function() {
    c_urn();
    react();
    track_record();
  });
  $("#id_urnA_blue").keyup(function() {
    c_urn();
    react();
    track_record();
  });
});

function c_urn() {}
function react() {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="id_urnA_red" />
<input id="id_urnA_blue" />
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="tracking" id="id_tracking" />
```

Here, `id_urnA_red` is an input element. When its value changes, I would like the value of `id_tracking` to change.
Other functions `c_urn` and `react` are implemented normally on key up. I am confused why `track_record` is not implemented.

Thank you

Comment: Basically the value of id_tracking is "a" no matter how I execute the keyup  part.

Comment: what is `c_urn()` and `react()`? Are you getting errors from either of these functions that prevent `track_record()` from executing? Have you verified that the keyup events are triggered? Is there any console errors in the dev tools?

Comment: Your code works correctly... Must be some errors in previous functions.

Comment: I would check the scope. We need to see more of the code, but your variable is probably getting set, and then being lost once you move outside the `().keyup() {}` method.

Comment: but it works in the example you provided ! Surely the issue comes from the other function (I don't think they're just empty one).